# "Reverse" sticky header

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to implement a header that is originally fixed and stays on top, then, as a certain element or scrolling position is reached, it will scroll out of the viewport as if it were "normal" content.

What I did until now is this code using the [Jquery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) plugin:

```
$('h1').waypoint(function(direction) {
    $(".header-container").slideToggle();
});
```

It basically animates the header out of sight as soon as a certain element (in this case `h1`) is reached. But I want it to be scrollable by the user.

I hope I made myself clear, it's kind of difficult to explain :)

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to replace [JQuery Wayppints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) with **[JQuery ScrollToFixed](https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed)**. Their **[Full demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZczEt/167/)** is just gorgeous. I think it does exactly what you're looking for.

```
$('.header').scrollToFixed({
    preFixed: function() { $(this).find('h1').css('color', 'blue'); },
    postFixed: function() { $(this).find('h1').css('color', ''); }
});
```

Comment: Yes that plugin did exactly what I needed using `$('.header-container').scrollToFixed({ limit: $($('h1')[1]).offset().top });` (in this case, the first `h1` "pushes" the header upwards.