# Reverse sticky navbar not appearing when position switches from fixed to static?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

**Situation**

I have a reverse sticky navbar where the navbar is in `position:fixed` at the top and when the top of a specific div container touches the bottom of the navbar, the `position:static` with jquery.

**Problem**

When the navbar becomes `position:static` the navbar disappears (please view code in full screen to see problem). I want the navbar to stick to the top of the div container while scrolling to the bottom of the page which means it scroll out of frame when position is not fixed. like this http://jsfiddle.net/vx8uc2rm/.

```js
var fixmeTop = $('.texttop').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop()+210;
    if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop) {
          $('.header-container').css({
            position: 'relative'
            
        });
    } else {
         $('.header-container').css({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: 0,
            left: 0
            
        });
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #fbfaf8;
    overscroll-behavior: none;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.myheroimage {
    background-color:palevioletred;
    min-height: 1400px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 0;
}

.header-container {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99;
    background-color: #fbfaf8;
    height: 180px;
}


header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    padding: 30px 120px;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
}

a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.mybutton {
    color: #191919;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

a.mybutton:hover {
    color: #758086;
}

a.mybutton1 {
    color: #35BDAF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.mybutton{
    margin-left: 44px;
}

.texttop {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin: 0 0 68px
}
.container-projects {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
    justify-content:flex-start;
    margin: 0 120px 120px;
}

.footer-container {
    background-color:#1E2224;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1rem;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 50px 120px 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css-reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com"> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Racing+Sans+One&family=Roboto:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="hiddenoverflow"></div>
<div class="myheroimage">
    <div class="header-container">
        <header>
            <div class="logo"></div>
      
        <nav>
        <a href="#" class="mybutton1">Title</a>
        <a href="#" class="mybutton">Title2</a>
        <a href="#" class="mybutton">Title3</a>
        </nav>
    
    
        </header>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="texttop">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>

<div class="container-projects">

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia quam tempora quibusdam in atque! Nobis explicabo, at facere, sint sunt voluptas ad nesciunt deleniti dolorem aliquid dolor repellendus hic labore?
  Facere ex debitis dolores minus nihil iusto veniam voluptatum nesciunt, maxime nobis esse architecto dignissimos ipsa? Architecto deleniti saepe vel maiores, quia alias maxime, dicta ea aliquid hic quis deserunt.
  Earum eum hic nam corporis necessitatibus unde provident, numquam omnis doloremque ad ducimus velit neque, repellat quisquam distinctio. Rem velit veniam reiciendis accusantium nam debitis tempora perspiciatis iste accusamus error!
  Suscipit at illo voluptatum eveniet error. Perferendis cupiditate atque rem architecto voluptates excepturi saepe assumenda earum delectus similique voluptatem sint voluptatibus ea, aperiam maiores perspiciatis error doloribus est blanditiis sit!
  Beatae recusandae delectus commodi omnis obcaecati quia atque, architecto aliquid sapiente vitae vero quasi veniam ipsam totam earum doloremque assumenda? Ut, ad. Tempora, necessitatibus voluptates qui sit natus eum assumenda.
  Eius molestias totam non optio? Totam laudantium odio tempore consequuntur laboriosam tempora, voluptas eligendi quae officiis ad necessitatibus optio quas excepturi voluptatibus doloremque provident numquam molestiae dolorum, exercitationem aliquid reprehenderit?
  Alias laboriosam, aperiam quas provident quibusdam in reprehenderit voluptatem officiis laborum. Deleniti, beatae molestiae. Minima cupiditate consequuntur, repudiandae quasi aliquam, autem, delectus suscipit ex similique vel doloremque cumque odio rem?
  Praesentium vel, voluptatem nam soluta reiciendis maiores quia hic pariatur eaque incidunt perspiciatis voluptatum debitis alias unde iure, accusamus dolorem dolor consectetur eos? Unde autem suscipit nihil corporis, sequi quis!
  Tempore suscipit iusto libero, illo doloremque cumque odio reprehenderit cupiditate quis, dignissimos porro officiis est error a enim optio accusantium? Maxime laborum totam ut quod iure iste. Aspernatur, minus porro!
  Natus inventore dolore, eveniet laudantium magni iste impedit? Voluptatibus inventore eius, illum voluptatem magnam non reprehenderit perspiciatis vitae qui, est error dolorem voluptas incidunt quia ipsa exercitationem expedita tempore autem?</p>
    </div>


<div class="footer-container">
   
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="stickyscroll.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! I just used scrollToFixed(); jquery plugin in my js file instead by bigsotteddog https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed#demos

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.header-container').scrollToFixed( { marginTop: 10, limit: 400 } );
```

The marginTop fixes the navbar/header to whichever height set, 0 is the top of the page and the limit is the scroll position/point in which it triggers the navbar to stop sticking.

This specific demo provided by the github page helped me understand how to use the plugin, http://jsfiddle.net/y3qV5/435/.

here's a link to a similar question I had that was answered on stackoverflow too, ["Reverse" sticky header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989439/reverse-sticky-header).

Answer (score 0):

Please check this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/dularnikode/742azj0x/5/  if it can solve your first problem.

You can use position "sticky" to solve your first problem.

```css
body {
  height: 3000px;
}

.content {
  background: blue;
  height: 500px;
}

.fixme {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position:sticky;
  top:0px;
}

.writehere {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixme">Scroll here</div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="writehere">hi</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! The demo you provided here is a standard sticky navbar though, I need the "scroll here" to be fixed at the top until `<div class="writehere">hi</div>` hits the bottom of `<div class="fixme">Scroll here</div>`. Then the two div containers stick to each other and scroll out of frame together.